# Try to convert recursive function by using 1 parameter: dfs(tar, num) -> dfs(tar)

Tags: javascript, algorithm

https://leetcode.com/problems/ways-to-express-an-integer-as-sum-of-powers

following code AC; the dfs(tar, num); uses 2 parameter tar, num

```
var numberOfWays = function(n, x) {
    const MOD = 10**9+7;

    const mem = new Array(301).fill(undefined).map((_, i) => {
        return new Array(301).fill(undefined);
    });

    const dfs = (tar, num) => {
        if(tar < 0) return 0;
        if(tar === 0) return 1;

        const tmp = Math.pow(num, x);
        if(tmp > tar) return 0;

        if(mem[tar][num] !== undefined) return mem[tar][num];

        const take = dfs(tar - tmp, num+1);
        const skip = dfs(tar, num+1);

        const out = (take + skip) % MOD;
        mem[tar][num] = out;
        return out;
    }

    return dfs(n, 1);
};
```

following code fail to AC; the dfs(tar); uses 1 parameter tar; It always restart from i=1 in internal loop.

```
var numberOfWays = function(n, x) {
    const MOD = 10 ** 9 + 7;

    const dfs = (tar) => {
        // * b: tar
        if(tar < 0) return 0;

        // * b: tar
        if(tar === 0) return 1;

        // * b: 1. min/max, res after loop
        // * b: 2. acc, res after loop
        let acc = 0;

        // * b: each time, restart from 1
        for(let i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
            // * b: curr
            const curr = Math.pow(i, x);
            if(curr > tar) continue;

            pick = dfs(tar - curr);
            acc = acc + pick;
        }

        return acc % MOD;
    }

    return dfs(n);
};


input:
n = 10, x = 2

my output:
16

exp output:
1
```

The above code is based on https://leetcode.com/problems/perfect-squares

```
var numSquares = function(n) {
    const hash = {};

    const dfs = (num) => {
        if(num === 0) return 0;

        if(hash[num] !== undefined) {
            return hash[num];
        }

        let min = Infinity;
        
        const half_num = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num));
        for(let i=1; i<=num; ++i) {
            if(i>half_num) continue;

            min = Math.min(min, 1 + dfs(num - i*i));
        }

        hash[num] = min;
        return min;
    }

    const res = dfs(n);
    return res;
};
```

In summary, I try to convert the dfs pattern by using internal loop within the recursive function
dfs(tar, num) ---> dfs(tar), but it fails to pass the test case.

Is it a way to just use the "tar param" in dfs(tar)?

Comment: ... and your question is?

Comment: @ScottSauyet, updated